# How to render fields in Sitecore MVC - Partial View

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

How can i render a field or image from template in my Partial View. I need to edit content by the Page Editor.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this but at the most basic level, you can render a field in your partial view by using the following syntax:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("myFieldName")
```

I recommend checking out John West's blog for more MVC-related tips: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/Posts-about-Using-MVC-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

There is also documentation on Sitecore's SDN site: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/MVC%20Reference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Access the value of your Field By using FieldRenderer.Render and Render it in the View @Html.Raw(Model.Urfieldname). This will work.

Thanks

Comment: You hardly ever want to use raw values in output. Don't use this code unless you know about raw values in Sitecore and you're certain that's what you want to do.